# Where is my data (directories) store by slapd (OpenLDAP) on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, openldap

After installation slapd on ubuntu 12.04 machine, `ldapadd`, `ldapsearch`, I can see it got my data.

The question is where is the directory? It's empty here:

```
/var/lib/ldap/
/usr/lib/ldap/
```

`slapd` configuration directory `/etc/ldap/` contains only root settings.

Where is my data? Or how to check/list my backend?

I do the following initializations:

```
sudo ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f db.ldif
```

The `db.ldif` is:

```bash
# Load modules for database type
dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectclass: olcModuleList
cn: module
olcModuleLoad: back_bdb.la
# Create directory database
dn: olcDatabase=bdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcBdbConfig
olcDatabase: bdb
# Domain name (e.g. home.local)
olcSuffix: dc=home,dc=local
# Location on system where database is stored
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
# Manager of the database
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=home,dc=local
olcRootPW: admin
# Indices in database to speed up searches
olcDbIndex: uid pres,eq
olcDbIndex: cn,sn,mail pres,eq,approx,sub
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
# Allow users to change their own password
# Allow anonymous to authenciate against the password
# Allow admin to change anyone's password
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword
  by self write
  by anonymous auth
  by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=home,dc=local" write
  by * none
# Allow users to change their own record
# Allow anyone to read directory
olcAccess: to *
  by self write
  by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=home,dc=local" write
  by * read
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using the new 'online conf option' (olc). Also as a backend you're loading the Berkeley database (bdb).

Can you please paste the output of the following command (which will list your current configuration, requires root/sudo):

```
ldapsearch -Q -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config dn
```

**Where is my data?**

Your data *should* be at the specified location `/var/lib/ldap`.

**how to check/list my backend?**

You can try the following, which should list all users under your local domain:

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap:/// -b dc=home,dc=local dn
```

You should have at least 1 entry from this query - the db manager:

```
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=home,dc=local
olcRootPW: admin
```

In general:

Make sure your ldap server is up and running:

```
ps ax | grep ldap
```

Your output should be something similar to:

```
/usr/sbin/slapd -h ldap:/// ldapi:/// -g openldap -u openldap -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d
```

You can use a graphical tool to visualise your LDAP. 
I would recommend just two - JXplorer (lightweight) or Apache's LDAP Directory Studio (heavier)

Comment: Nice, I just found data pupulated in `/var/lib/ldap`. Keep wonderring why it only appeared after one day's testing. But it should be normal when testing new things. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the default configuration, slapd's database files are in `/var/lib/ldap` not the intuitively obvious `/var/lib/slapd` which is normally empty.